# strong convergence of product of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm trying to prove the next:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Consider $\{T_{n}\}$ and $\{S_{n}\}$ sequences of $\mathcal{B}(H)$ such that $S_{n}\xrightarrow{s} S$ and $T_{n}\xrightarrow{s}T;$ here $S_{n}\xrightarrow{s} S$ means that $S_{n}$ converges strongly to $S,$ i.e. for each $x\in H,$ $S_{n}x\rightarrow Sx.$

Then $S_{n}T_{n}\xrightarrow{s}ST.$

So, for $x\in H,$ We have $||(S_{n}T_{n}-ST)x||\leq||(S_{n}-S)T_{n}x||+||S||||(T_{n}-T)x||.$

The second term of right side of the inequality above converges to zero. My doubt comes from the other term. If $y_{n}=T_{n}x$ it would seem such term converges to zero too because of the strong convergence of $S_{n},$ but such $y_{n}$ depends of $n;$ I have doubts about it.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One uses Uniform Boundedness Principle to conclude that $\sup_{n}\|S_{n}\|<\infty$. With such, one has $$\|S_{n}T_{n}x-S_{n}Tx\|\leq\left(\sup_{n}\|S_{n}\|\right)\cdot\|T_{n}x-Tx\|$$ and we split $$\|S_{n}T_{n}x-STx\|\leq\|S_{n}T_{n}x-S_{n}Tx\|+\|S_{n}Tx-STx\|.$$

Comment: so nice! Thank you for your help!

Comment: So does the second summand just split into $\|S_n - S\| \|Tx\|$ and then the first norm disappears due to strong convergence?

Comment: Don't do in that way, it won't work. Simply let $y=Tx$ and use the definition of strong convergence to get $S_{n}y\rightarrow Sy$.